# How to configure apache-vhost.conf file for getting Session value from Java

Tags: java, session, tomcat, virtualhost, mod-proxy

**Existing Config File** setting for **VirtualHost** in **Tomcat Server**:

```
`<VirtualHost *:96>
  ServerName example.in
  ServerAlias www.example.in
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/example/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/example/

  <IfModule mod_jk.c>
  JkMount /*.jsp ajp13
  JkMount /*.do ajp13
  JkMount /*.* ajp13
  JkMount /servlet/* ajp13
  JkMount /servlets/* ajp13
</IfModule>
</VirtualHost>`
```

By using this configuration I am not able to get the Session Value, which is being set in Java file `request.getSession().setAttribute("ActiveSession", output.getParameters().get("userDetailsList"));`

I am trying to retrieve the value in jsp by standard jsp code as `<%session.getAttribute("ActiveSession")%>`

**Problem**: 
when I am using website link 'example.in' I'm not getting the session value in JSP.

But using http://127.0.0.1:8080/example/ I am getting the value.

**Already Tried** :

```
`<VirtualHost *:96>
  ServerName example.in
  ServerAlias www.example.in
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/example/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/example/
  Session On
  SessionEnv On
  SessionCookieName session path=/
  SessionHeader X-Replace-Session
  <IfModule mod_jk.c>
  JkMount /*.jsp ajp13
  JkMount /*.do ajp13
  JkMount /*.* ajp13
  JkMount /servlet/* ajp13
  JkMount /servlets/* ajp13
</IfModule>
```

`

Help will be appreciated as I have already wasted 5 good hrs on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is still struggling to get this, here is the working configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:96>
 ServerName example.in
 ServerAlias www.example.in
 ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/example/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/example/
 ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / http://127.0.0.1:8080/example/
 <IfModule mod_jk.c>
  JkMount /*.jsp ajp13
  JkMount /*.do ajp13
  JkMount /*.* ajp13
  JkMount /servlet/* ajp13
  JkMount /servlets/* ajp13
 </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```