# Session Keeps Getting Recreated

Tags: apache, session, server, payara

i have a single payara instance. have been able to configure request forwarding from my apache web server to my payara. however upon every reload of a page using the actual domain url i have, the session gets recreated hence losing any attributes stored in the session from the previous request. However, same does not occur when i access my application via the ipaddress instead of the domain name

i am using a centos8 vps. didnt find **mod_session** as part of the modules in the **/etc/httpd/modules** folders so i installed using

**yum install mod_sessions**

and after running successfully checked and they were now in the modules folder. so i then edited the **/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/01-session.conf** with the following lines

```
**LoadModule session_module modules/mod_session.so
LoadModule request_module modules/mod_request.so
LoadModule session_cookie_module modules/mod_session_cookie.so
LoadModule session_dbd_module modules/mod_session_dbd.so
LoadModule auth_form_module modules/mod_auth_form.so
LoadModule session_crypto_module modules/mod_session_crypto.so**
```

and then restarted the apache httpd server.

however, still doesn't work. visiting the webpage via the domain name recreates a new session at every request.

this is my current virtual host file setting

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName www.someapp.com
        ServerAlias someapp.com

        Session On
        SessionEnv On
        SessionCookieName session path=/

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/someapp/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/someapp/

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule "^/someapp/?$" "home.jsp" [NC]
        #RewriteRule ^/someapp/(.*)$ /$1 [NC]

</VirtualHost>
```

NOTE: ***someapp*** is not the name of the real app. just using that name in this example but u get the idea

i really need help. am unable to make login pages on my website work because once i enter the login details and after validation the user is set in the session, upon redirecting or making another request, new session gets created and i lose the user and am back to the login screen again of my application. please i need help

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone facing this same problem as i did, the answer was to introduce the **ProxyPassReverseCookiePath** in the VirtualHost config file in the apache httpd conf files such that now your VirtualHost looks something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName www.someapp.com
    ServerAlias someapp.com

    Session On
    SessionEnv On
    SessionCookieName session path=/

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/someapp/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/someapp/
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / http://localhost:8080/someapp/

</VirtualHost>
```

Also, major thank you to the similar issue solved on [How to configure apache-vhost.conf file for getting Session value from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34693637/how-to-configure-apache-vhost-conf-file-for-getting-session-value-from-java)